# FastAPI pydantic data validation for put method if body only contains the updated data

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am learning FastAPI and understanding that its data validation using **pydantic** is one of its features. But after reading its put method example from [its tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-updates/) I have a question if I only want to let the put body contain the updated data(as the URL already has its id), how do I do that?

Use the sample code from the tutorial as an example to what I mean,

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str
    description:  str = "default description"
    price: Union[float, None] = None
    tax: float = 10.5
    tags: list[str] = []

...

@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
#async def update_item(item_id: str, item:Item):
async def update_item(item_id: str, item):
    pass
```

If I code `async def update_item(item_id: str, item:Item)` then the body has to contain id property otherwise I will get `422 "field required"`. But I feel that is unnecessary because the URL `/items/{item_id}` already contains the `id` I just want body to contain the updated data.

But when I coded `async def update_item(item_id: str, item)`, to my surprise the item became the **required** QUERY PARAMETERS!

As its document shows:

[image: put with query parameters]

Why does it become query parameters then? This is my second question.

I feel that is wrong because I prefer to query parameters for GET only.

**--- Update ---**

I guess the 2 methods Chris provided are the way FastAPI solves my first question (whether `id` should be one of Item's properties is another question, e.g. check [What to do when REST POST provides an ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452765/what-to-do-when-rest-post-provides-an-id)), but I come from nodejs background so I would like to provide Nestjs solution in comparison.

Using Nestjs sample code here https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#full-resource-sample

```
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  @Post()
  create(@Body() createCatDto: CreateCatDto) {
    return 'This action adds a new cat';
  }

...

  @Put(':id')
  update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() updateCatDto: UpdateCatDto) {
    return `This action updates a #${id} cat`;
  }
```

As https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#mapped-types explains "The `PartialType()` function returns a type (class) with all the properties of the input type set to optional."

```
export class CreateCatDto {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}

export class UpdateCatDto extends PartialType(CreateCatDto) {}
```

Comment: You could define the `item` parameter as Optional - have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804).

Comment: I know that but I feel that is kind of defeats the purpose of defining the id property.

Comment: "Why's that?" because for post method I want id to be present. so I can code `async def create_item(item: Item)`

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804) and its references as well.

Comment: It is not an extra line of code that makes this over-complicated its the concept behind it, using a subclass to solve this makes me feel over-complicated. It is supposed to a simple question (at least to me).

Comment: If there is a situation that does require a subclass model,  id still should be in the base class. Now we put it in the subclass just to solve a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

You could have a Pydantic model, which would act as the parent one and include every attribute that is shared between both `POST` and `PUT` request bodies. You could then create a submodel, containing only the `id` attribute and inheriting from the parent model (not the `BaseModel`), which would be used for `POST` requests. The example below is based on the one given in [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-updates/#update-replacing-with-put). Some related answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71228281/17865804).

##### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union, List

app = FastAPI()


class Item(BaseModel):
    description:  str = "default description"
    price: Union[float, None] = None
    tax: float = 10.5
    tags: List[str] = []
    

class ItemCreate(Item):
    id: str


items = {
    "foo": {"name": "Foo", "price": 50.2},
    "bar": {"name": "Bar", "description": "The bartenders", "price": 62, "tax": 20.2},
    "baz": {"name": "Baz", "description": None, "price": 50.2, "tax": 10.5, "tags": []},
}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}", response_model=Union[Item,str])
async def read_item(item_id: str):
    if item_id in items:
        return items[item_id]
    else:
        return 'Item not found'
    

@app.put("/items/{item_id}", response_model=Item)
async def update_item(item_id: str, item: Item):
    update_item_encoded = jsonable_encoder(item)
    items[item_id] = update_item_encoded
    return update_item_encoded
    

@app.post("/items")
async def create_item(item: ItemCreate):
    new_item_encoded = jsonable_encoder(item)
    items[item.id] = new_item_encoded
    return 'Success'
```

**Alternatively**, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), you could use the same `Item` model for both `PUT` and `POST` requests, with an extra `id` parameter explicitly defined as `Body` in the `create_item` endpoint for `POST` requests. For instance:

```py
from fastapi import Body

@app.post("/items")
async def create_item(item: Item, id: str = Body(...)):
    new_item_encoded = jsonable_encoder(item)
    items[id] = new_item_encoded
    return 'Success'
```

In that case, the request body would look like this:

```json
{
  "item": {
    "description": "default description",
    "price": 0,
    "tax": 10.5,
    "tags": []
  },
  "id": "string"
}
```

### Solution 2

With regard to the recent update in your question, indicating that (1) `item_id` should not be left to the client to decide/pass it (which is what you asked for initally), but rather be auto-created on server side (by your db or some other mechanism), and (2) should have the `ItemUpdate` model inheriting from the `Item` model with all the fields being optional (as shown in the Nest.js example you provided), here's a working example on how to approach the problem in that way. The `@optional` decorator in `utlis.py` module below has been taken from [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1223#issuecomment-1633592384), which is an update of [this original post](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1223#issuecomment-775363074), so that is compatible with Pydantic V2. Additional related posts around creating an `optional`/`partial` decorator can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699451), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65883869), [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/3089) and [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1673). There also seems to be a related package, namely [`pydantic-partial`](https://github.com/team23/pydantic-partial) (haven't tested it though).

##### Working Example

**main.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, HTTPException
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union, List
from utils import optional
import random
import string

app = FastAPI()

items = {
    "foo": {"name": "Foo", "price": 50.2},
    "bar": {"name": "Bar", "description": "The bartenders", "price": 62, "tax": 20.2},
    "baz": {"name": "Baz", "description": None, "price": 50.2, "tax": 10.5, "tags": []},
}


class Item(BaseModel):
    description: str = "default description"
    price: Union[float, None] = None
    tax: float = 10.5
    tags: List[str] = []
 

@optional
class ItemUpdate(Item):
    pass

   
def check_item_id(item_id):
    if item_id not in items:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Item not found')

        
@app.get("/items/{item_id}", response_model=Union[Item, str])
async def read_item(item_id: str):
    check_item_id(item_id)
    return items[item_id]

   
@app.post("/items")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    item_encoded = jsonable_encoder(item)
    item_id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=5))
    items[item_id] = item_encoded
    return f"Item '{item_id}' has been created"
    

@app.put("/items/{item_id}", response_model=Union[Item, str])
async def update_item(item_id: str, item: ItemUpdate):
    check_item_id(item_id)
    old = items[item_id]
    new = jsonable_encoder(item)
    old.update((k,v) for k,v in new.items() if v is not None)
    return old
```

**utils.py**

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic import create_model
from typing import Optional
import inspect

def optional(*fields):
    def dec(cls):
        fields_dict = {}
        for field in fields:
            field_info = cls.__annotations__.get(field)
            if field_info is not None:
                fields_dict[field] = (Optional[field_info], None)
        OptionalModel = create_model(cls.__name__, **fields_dict)
        OptionalModel.__module__ = cls.__module__

        return OptionalModel

    if fields and inspect.isclass(fields[0]) and issubclass(fields[0], BaseModel):
        cls = fields[0]
        fields = cls.__annotations__
        return dec(cls)

    return dec
```

### About Query Parameters

As for the query parameters, the `HTTP` protocol does not prevent one from using query params when sending a request using `PUT`, `POST`, etc., methods. Hence, in FastAPI, when declaring other endpoint parameters that are not part of the path parameters, such as `item_id` path parameter in the example above, or explicitly declared otherwise, such as `Item` in the given example, they are automatically interpreted as query parameters of type `str`. That's the reason that `item` is expected as query parameter when removing the `Item` definition from it. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74536449/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72068032/17865804) for more details.

Comment: I feel this is over-complicated, I just need PUT with the body parameter containing the updated data while its id on path. How?

Comment: I am new to FastAPI as a matter of fact this is the **first** day I have started to learn it because we have a project using FastAPI.  I accept your answer. Thanks for spending in in doing it. But I have to say this one only makes me realize I don't want to use FastAPI other than this project. I don't like it at all (compared with some other web frameworks I am familair with).

Comment: I would also suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804)

Comment: I have checked all your answers. Thanks. I also updated my question to show how NestJS solves this.

Comment: Yes, @optional decorator you added is basically what `PartialType()` does in Next.js. I come to realize that my initial (and innocent) question, i.e. put method should better have optional body parameters has become a long discussion. Thanks.

Comment: This should be a separate topic but another reason when I said I don't want to FastAPI was because I saw Uvicorn only supports HTTP/1.1 while nodejs supports HTTP/2 since 8.6 (now is nodejs 20) so it was kind of  what?! But anyway I should not jump to that conclusion.

Comment: Uvicorn is not the only ASGI server that can be used for development or production. In fact, there is [Hypercorn and Daphne](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/manually/) that support HTTP/2. You could also use HTTP/2 with a reverse proxy like NGINX or Traefik (see [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/)), and run Uvicorn (or [Gunicorn with Uvicorn](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers)) behind it over HTTP/1.1. This would allow the proxy server to handle the performance intensive side (HTTPS, HTTP/2, etc.) and proxy the actual data to the server.